# What happens with cards hosted on Builder after moving it to another server?

Tags: android-netrunner

Consider [Builder](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07016) with installment(s). A [Patch](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07021) for example. What happens with it after the Builder being moved to another server? Nothing, I suppose? Seems like all the installments move with the Builder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From FAQ:

> Hosting
>
> The following replaces the rules on hosting that appear in the
> core set rulebook:
>
> “Hosting” is the result of placing a card, counter,
> or token on top of a card, creating a relationship between the host
> card and what is hosted. If a card allows other cards to be hosted on
> it, those cards must be hosted on the card when they are installed,
> unless a card says otherwise.
>
> Hosted counters or tokens can be spent
> without affecting their host. If a trigger cost requires one or more
> hosted counters or tokens, those counters or tokens are “spent” by
> being returned to the token bank from the card the ability appears on.
>
> If a host is trashed or uninstalled, all cards, counters, and tokens
> hosted on it are also trashed. This cannot be prevented. If a host
> Corp card is derezzed, all cards, counters, and tokens hosted on it
> remain hosted.
>
> The state of hosting is distinct (but not exclusive
> from) the state of installing. Most cards are hosted on another card
> when they are installed.

So, conditions under which hosting ends are "trashed or uninstalled", moving doesn't affect hosting. Anything hosted on Builder will remain hosted on Builder after it moves.